# how to change border color in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Could you please tell me  How to make border red in react ui material ?
Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/942m24jl0y

**Currently when I focus my input field it show border in blue color**

[image]

I already added these lines

```
underlineInput: {
        '&:before': {
            borderBottom: '1px solid #777777'
        },
        '&:after': {
            borderBottom: `2px solid #777777`
        },
        '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error):before': {
            borderBottom: `2px solid #777777`
        }
    },
```

I want to change border color to `red`

Answer (score 1):

Add `classNamePrefix="my-select"` to your Select component: `<Select classNamePrefix="my-select"/>`

and add next styles to your `styles.css` file `.my-select__input{ color: red;}`.